# Android/OkHttp - client.newCall(request).execute() always return exception

Tags: android, request, okhttp

I have to make an android application project. At first, I tried to use HttpURLConnection but it didn't work.  So after a discussion with a friend, I tried to use OkHttp. I all time got an exception for "responses = client.newCall(request).execute();". After long hours of searching, I just try this code, which is the tutorial of "https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes"
And..... It doesn't work too !
My question is, what is really happening? I'm currently developping a 4.0.3 application under Android Studio 1.5.1. I also add the two following dependencies:

```
// DEPENDENCIES
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

// Class Http
public static String run(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("login", "Mr. X")
                .add("password", "********")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response responses = null;

        try {
            Log.d("DEBUGG ", "----------------------------------");
            responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d("DEBUGG ", "----------------------------------");
            return (responses.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String jsonData = responses.body().string();
        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("employees");

        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
    return null;
}

// MainActivity
private TextView textView;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewJSon);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Hit);

    textView.setText("Hello !");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                textView.setText(Http.run("https://epitech-api.herokuapp.com/login"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You cannot run network IO on main thread ... `newCall(request).execute()` does not creat new thread ...

Answer (score 4):

**{ ANSWER }** 
I finally tried to use multi-threading programming like said Selvin and it works well So the solution is to open another thread

```
public static int responseCode = 0;
public static String responseString = "";

public static Thread login = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private String url = "https://epitech-api.herokuapp.com/login";
    private User user = User.getUser();

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Build the request
            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("login", user._login)
                .add("password", user._password)
                .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
            Response responses = null;

            // Reset the response code
            responseCode = 0;

            // Make the request
            responses = client.newCall(request).execute();

            if ((responseCode = responses.code()) == 200) {
                // Get response
                String jsonData = responses.body().string();

                // Transform reponse to JSon Object
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                // Use the JSon Object
                user._token = json.getString("token");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: or you could have used the `.enqueue()` so the request would be handled in the background and you get the result

Comment: I also use code like above. but with thread my button onClickListener not working on first  click because of thread(button work on second click), but if i remove thread then my "responses = client.newCall(request).execute();" not working, do you have any solution??

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, since Honeycomb, network operation in main thread is restricted. So, calling the `execute()` method is useful when you are already in background thread. But if you are in the main thread then `enqueue()` will be helpful as it will process the network request in background thread and return the response in main thread. In that case, you just need to pass a callback to get the response.

As you mentioned, using Okhttp is a suggestion from your friend. I also want to recommend you to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). It will make your code nicer and maintainable and also handle the threading on behalf of you. Under the hood, it uses Okhttp. More importantly, since [version 2.6.0](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) you can feel the synchronous experience with the help of [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).